# Issue connecting to new SqlServer instance

Tags: sql-server, ssms

It's acting like the instance name doesn't exist.  The service is started too.

I hope someone else can shed some light. I installed a fresh instance that is named "SqlExpress2014". I ran the command:

```
reg.exe query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"
```

and that returns

> SQLEXPRESS2014    REG_SZ    MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS2014

I have tried connecting to this instance name via SSMS (both with the "MSSQL12." prefix and without), yet the error given is:

Cannot connect to MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS2014.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

---

The network path was not found

Comment: Your link is wrong. are you connecting locally or remotely?

Comment: heh, thanks for mentioning. Yet - the link is directly from SSMS 2014, so nothing I can help with there.

I'm connecting locally.  On Windows 10 Home.  Any solutions that come to mind?

Comment: if you cannot connect through SSMS, you'll get an error. right?

Comment: I updated the OP to mention ssms. Still have the issue

Comment: Using "Sql Server Configuration Manager", make sure TCP/IP is enabled on both server and client side. This is the most common reason. But I suggest you check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me.  I was going through the suggestions linked.  In Sql config mgr, switching to TCP/IP enabled didn't help. I restarted all ~4 sql services as well. And I've disabled my firewall temporarily again too just in case. I see port 1434 on UDP would need to be opened  

Tomorrow morn will try a reboot after a big backup I have running is completed

Comment: Thanks. I've checked that out, and rebooted too. Same issue :(  Double checked the  setting for TCP/IP is enabled, and also again tried disabling McAfee firewall.  It's a local to local connection on win10, if that helps. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The last thing is check if you have an Anti virus that might block SQL Server port. No other clue :(

Comment: Hmm... no go. Any ideas on TCP/IP window?  btw, AV and firewall both turned off.  For TCP/IP port setup I do have an issue.  For some reason when I right click and choose "Properties" on "TCP/IP" in windows10, it doesn't pull up the dialog window for that. The other nodes in general in the treeview do pop up dialogs just fine. Anyone have this issue and ideas for getting through it?